# read value member from combobox populated using dictionary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, combobox, .net-4.0

I have populated `combobox` using `dictionary` on the event of  `form_load` with value and display member as below

```
Dictionary<string, int> GravelCount = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {1,"text value 1"},
    {2,"text value 2"},
};

CB_GravelCount.DataSource = new BindingSource(GravelCount, null);
CB_GravelCount.DisplayMember = "Key";
CB_GravelCount.ValueMember = "Value";
CB_GravelCount.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

this value member are stored into sql server database... everything works fine until I am trying to read this stored data and re-assign to `combobox` on the event of  `form_load` the data wot be assigned the combobox value show nothing as it gets the index -1 with no errors

```
public int GetPersonification()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRJDconnstr"].ToString();
    string cmdStr = @"SELECT ID,
                                             SIZ,
                                             PLACE,
                                             ONE_OR_MORE,
                                             R_OR_L,
                                             EKO_OR_ASH,
                                             NOTICE
                                     FROM PERSONIFICATION
                                   WHERE SEANCE_ID=@SEANCE_ID;";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
    {

            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SEANCE_ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = F0102.vSessionID;

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                PersonificationID = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader[0].ToString());
                TB_Size.Text = sqlReader[1].ToString();                              //SIZ
                CB_TreatmentPlace.SelectedValue = sqlReader[2].ToString(); //PLACE
                CB_GravelCount.SelectedValue = sqlReader[3].ToString();      //ONE_OR_MORE
                CB_Side.SelectedValue = sqlReader[4].ToString();                 //R_OR_L
                CB_TreatmentWay.SelectedValue = sqlReader[5].ToString(); //EKO_OR_ASH
                TB_Note.Text = sqlReader[6].ToString();                             //NOTICE
            }
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: GravelCount is Dictionary<string, int> but values are <int,string>. does it compile?

Comment: @ErcanPeker yes it is compile and when I tried to make it <int,string> I got errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse to int.

`CB_GravelCount.SelectedValue = int.Parse(sqlReader[3].ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an error when reading from the database. Put a try/catch around the SqlDataReader portion of your code to see what exactly is failing. My guess is that you have a null value for one of the columns of data which causes the ToString to fail or the Convert.ToInt32 for PersonificationId is failing. Reading the exception message that is returned will most likely put you in the right direction.
Try this:

```
public int GetPersonification()
{
  string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRJDconnstr"].ToString();
  string cmdStr = @"SELECT ID,
                          SIZ,
                        PLACE,
                  ONE_OR_MORE,
                        R_OR_L,
                    EKO_OR_ASH,
                        NOTICE
          FROM PERSONIFICATION
          WHERE SEANCE_ID=@SEANCE_ID;";

  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
  {
    //Add the try here
    try
    {
      conn.Open();
      cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SEANCE_ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = F0102.vSessionID;

      SqlDataReader sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      int? persId = null;
      string siz,
      string place = "";
      string one_or_more = "";
      string r_or_l = "";
      string eko_or_ash = "";
      string notice = "";
      while (sqlReader.Read())
      {
          persId = sqlReader["ID"] as int? ?? default(int);
          siz = sqlReader["SIZ"] as string;
          place = sqlReader["PLACE"] as string;
          one_or_more = sqlReader["ONE_OR_MORE"] as string;
          r_or_l = sqlReader["R_OR_L"] as string;
          eko_or_ash = sqlReader["EKO_OR_ASH"] as string;
          notice = sqlReader["NOTICE"] as string;
      }
      PersonificationID = persId ?? 0; //null coalesce
      TB_Size.Text = siz;
      CB_TreatmentPlace.SelectedValue = place;
      CB_GravelCount.SelectedValue = one_or_more;
      CB_Side.SelectedValue = r_or_l;
      CB_TreatmentWay.SelectedValue = eko_or_ash;
      TB_Note.Text = notice;
      return 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      //Read the exception message using your debugger.
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got no errors or exceptions with or without exception part btw way values may has null values

Comment: I changed the code so that you should be able to see the return values of the query. Step through this code to see if you can detect the error.